# Failing to install Stalin Scheme on OSX because it is "not supported yet" - is there any workaround?

Tags: macos, installation, scheme

I've downloaded Stalin Scheme and tried to install it on OSX, but I've got this error:

```
gcc  -O -I./include -DATOMIC_UNCOLLECTABLE -DNO_SIGNALS -DNO_EXECUTE_PERMISSION -DSILENT -DALL_INTERIOR_POINTERS -DLARGE_CONFIG -DUSE_MMAP -DDONT_ADD_BYTE_AT_END -o if_mach ./if_mach.c
In file included from ./if_mach.c:3:
./include/private/gcconfig.h:477: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘--’ token
./if_mach.c: In function ‘main’:
./if_mach.c:14: error: ‘MACH_TYPE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
./if_mach.c:14: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
./if_mach.c:14: error: for each function it appears in.)
make: *** [if_mach] Error 1
cp: gc6.8/gc.a: No such file or directory
ranlib: can't open file: include/libgc.a (No such file or directory)
Cannot (yet) run Stalin on this architecture
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I don't know much about macs, but there is a [Chicken egg](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/stalin) that installs Stalin as a module on Mac. Maybe you find some clues there?